# JOIN the table if records exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

is it possible if i want to do INNER JOIN only if the record exist on the 2nd table if not then dont join?

this is my table

**User** table

```
+--------+--------------+
|   id   |     name     | 
+--------+--------------+
|   1    | John         |
+--------+--------------+
|   2    | Josh         | 
+--------+--------------+
```

**House** table

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+ 
|   id   |   owner_id  |   house_no   |
+--------+-------------+--------------+
|   1    |      1      |      991     | 
+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

this is my INNER JOIN query

```
SELECT h.owner_id, u.name, h.house_no FROM user u
INNER JOIN house h on u.id = h.owner_id 
WHERE u.id = :id
```

it will return this result if `id = 1`

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+ 
|   id   |     name     |   house_no   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+
|   1    | John         |      991     | 
+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

but if i run with `id = 2` no result returned.

what i want to do right now is it still return the result even when no data exist for `id = 2` in table house

Comment: This is exactly how `inner join` works. Only Matching Rows.

Comment: oh i see. i didn't know that. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join instead.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, h.house_no FROM user u
LEFT OUTER JOIN house h on u.id = h.owner_id 
WHERE u.id = :id
```

The resulting record will be:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+ 
|   id   |     name     |   house_no   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+
|   2    |     Josh     |     null     | 
+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: yeah this works. i didn't know that INNER JOIN only return matching result.

Comment: @j.Doe here is good reference for how the joins work https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/